# Global variables referencing in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, global-variables

I am trying to write a program with python functions.  The variables used in one function will be needed in various other functions.

I have declared it as global in the first function, then used the returned value in the second function.  However in the third function, I would like to use the updated value from the second, but I am only able to get the values from the first function.

```
def func():
    global val, val2
    val = 3
    val2 = 4
    return val, val2

def func1(val, val2):
    val = val + 1 
    val2 = val2 + 1
    return val, val2

def func2(val,val2):
    val = val + 1
    val2 = val2 + 1
    print val, val2

func()
func1(val, val2)
func2(val, val2)
```

I would like to get `5,6` as the answer, but am getting `4,5`.

Comment: you're mixing globals and locals. When you pass a variable to a function that variable is a local variable. Remove the function arguments and add global val, val2 to the beginning of all the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the return values of your functions to `val` and `val2`.

```
val, val2 = func()
val, val2 = func1(val, val2)
func2(val, val2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is declared as a function argument, it's a local variable for this function. In Your case if You declare `def func1(val,val2):` then `val,val2` will both be local in function `func1`. If You want to use global variables do it like that:

```
def func():
    global val,val2
    val=3
    val2=4
    return val,val2
def func1():
    global val,val2
    val=val+1
    val2=val2+1
    return val,val2
def func2():
    global val,val2
    val=val+1
    val2=val2+1
    print val,val2
func()
func1()
func2()
```

returns:

```
5 6
```

But I think that using global variables should be avoided if using them is not necessary (check [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)). Consider using `return` the right way like in pp_'s answer.